# Keystone.js isAdmin var mentioned in documentation not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, keystonejs, keystonejs6

I'm currently working on a KeystoneJS project and encountering an issue with TypeScript. I've defined an access control function, isAdmin, as suggested in the KeystoneJS [documentation](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/auth-and-access-control):

```
const isAdmin = ({ session }: { session: Session }) => session?.data.isAdmin;
```

However, when I use this function in the access configuration for list operations (create, delete) in my schema.ts, TypeScript throws the following error:

```
Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type 'ListOperationAccessControl<"create" | "delete", TypeInfo<any>>'.
Types of parameters '__0' and 'args' are incompatible.
Type 'BaseAccessArgs<TypeInfo<any>> & { operation: "create"; }' is not assignable to type '{ session: Session; }'.
Property 'session' is optional in type 'BaseAccessArgs<TypeInfo<any>> & { operation: "create"; }' but required in type '{ session: Session; }'.
```

Here's a simplified version of my schema.ts:

```
import { list } from "@keystone-6/core";
import type { Lists } from ".keystone/types";

type Session = {
  data: {
    id: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
  };
};

const isAdmin = ({ session }: { session: Session }) => session?.data.isAdmin;

export const lists: Lists = {
  User: list({
    access: {
      operation: {
        create: isAdmin,
        delete: isAdmin,
      },
      // ... other access controls
    },
    fields: {
      // ... other fields
    },
  }),

  // ... other lists
};
```

Additionally, I find it interesting that the built-in allowAll function in node_modules/@keystone-6/core/src/access.ts, which simply returns true, works without any issues.

```
export function allowAll() {
  return true;
}
```

But when I tried to the same thing for isAdmin is still does not work.

```
function isAdmin() {
  return true;
}
```

I tried to debug by using the valid inbuilt function (allowAll) as local function (isAdmin) with same logic but it still doesn't work.

When I run `npm run dev` it still works, but when I run `npm run test` it wouldn't.

npm run test is just running jest.

Answer (score 0):

You got two different cases:

First

```
const isAdmin = ({ session }: { session: Session }) => session?.data.isAdmin;
```

Because the session variable can be of type "undefined" you can't return "undefined", so you need to place something to force the return as boolean like:

```
const isAdmin = ({ session }: { session: Session }) => Boolean(session?.data.isAdmin);
```

Second

```
function isAdmin() {  return true; }
```

You can place that function in access as general but at the specific operations, you must define all the operations, query, create, update, delete.

```
{
access: {
  operation: {
    query: isAdmin,
    create: isAdmin,
    update: isAdmin,
    delete: isAdmin,
  }
},
```